# If an $ m \times n$ linear system is consistent where $m < n$, then how many parameters does the solution have?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If an $m \times n$ linear system is consistent where $m < n$, then how many parameters does the solution have?

I'm really not sure how to proceed, and I kept trying solutions to prove whether it would be true or not. I want to know if the statement above has a solution, or is it blatantly false?

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! Is it a *linear* system?

Comment: yes, I'm sorry I forgot to mention that

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you mean ‘on how many parameters does the set of solutions depend’.

Interpret the matrix of the linear system as the matrix of a linear map $f$ from $K^n$ to $K^m$ ($K$ is the base field).

- If the linear system is homogeneous, the set of solutions is $\ker f$ (a subspace of $K^n$), the dimension of the image of $f$ is the rank of the matrix ($\le m$ with your hypothesis), and the dimensions formula asserts that
  $$\dim\ker f+\operatorname{rank}f= n,$$
  so that the rank of the matrix is the *codimension* of the subspace of solutions.
- If the linear system is non-homogeneous, it is consistent if and only if the matrix of the linear map and the augmented matrix  have the same rank. In this case, the set of solutions is an affine subspace of $K^n$, directed by $\ker f$, and the codimension of this affine subspace is, again, the rank of the matrix.